# Is there any way to get subrecord without unsafeCoerce?

Tags: purescript

```
type Foo = {
  x :: Int,
  y :: Int
}

type Bar = {
  x :: Int
}

foo :: Foo
foo = {x:1,y:2}
bar :: Bar
bar = foo
```

> Could not match type
>
> ()
>
> with type
>
> ( y :: Int
>     )

Why isn't this possible?

I cannot use

```
type Bar a = {
  x :: Int | a
}
```

And don't want to recreate the record

```
bar = {x : foo.x}
```

Is `unsafeCoerce` the only option?

What could be the problem with use of `unsafeCoerce`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write functions deal with records that only have some specific fields then you can use an open row instead:

```
bar :: forall r. { x :: Int | r } -> { x :: Int | r }
bar rec = rec
```

That will still be compatible with both `Foo` and `Bar` synonyms.

However, if that's no good either and you do just want to "forget" about `y` then `unsafeCoerce` should be okay to use, as long as you only ever coerce `Foo` to `Bar`, and not back again.

I'd strongly recommend aliasing `unsafeCoerce` rather than using it directly though:

```
forget :: Foo -> Bar
forget = Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce
```

It's easy to make mistakes when using it directly even when you think you are using it in a principled way.

Personally, I'd just make a new record without the fields, even though it involves some boilerplate.

Comment: Is there any reason why it isn't possible to use `bar = foo::Bar` or it's just not implemented?

Comment: The short answer is we wouldn't want the type system to work that way. There are some philosophical reasons why, but here's a very concrete one: if you could do that, then you could also disappear effects from types unsafely.

Comment: But you already can do it by creating a new record `{x : foo.x}`. So `a :: B`  could be converted to `{x : a.x, y : b.y, ...}`.